# React Loop Question - TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone please explain to me why this code is giving me a blank page while I run the production build along the following error in the console when I don't get the same error in the npm start...

**Console Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefine
```

**Function:**

```
  const SearchView = (e) => {
    // setSearchValue(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    // const values = (Object.values(rows));
    console.log(e.target.value)

    if (!e.target.value) {
      setSearchDataSuggestions([])
      setSearchField(null)


    } else {

      setSearchField(true)
      props.setSeachingView(true)
      for (const row of Object.values(rows)) {
        Object.keys(row).forEach(function (item, index) {
          // console.log('[' + index + '] ' + 'keys: ' + item + ' values : ' + row[item]);


          if (typeof(row[item]) === 'string' && row[item].toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim())) {
            setSearchDataSuggestions([...search_data_suggestions, (rows[index])   ])
            // console.log('Got search as: ' + e.target.value + ' and updated with the row: ' + (rows[index]) )

          }

        });
        }

    }

  }
```

I suspect the is causing by the following state hook update ...

```
 setSearchDataSuggestions([...search_data_suggestions, (rows[index])   ])
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: where does id actually come from

Comment: Is it async code? If you pass React event into async function you have to call e.persist(). React optimises events by using events pool

Comment: I don't know! :( search_data_suggestions is an array of objects rows[index] is a single object that needs to merge into search_data_suggestions. Don't know if helps :(

Comment: its not an async code. funny thing is that it works fine on npm start, but wont work in the final build...

Comment: I’m sorry but currently nothing useful is posted. 

In browser console that error message can be expanded. Read the error stack and pinpoint where that `.id` access happens. Production minified code can be hard to read, but be patient, you can find it.

Comment: If you really don’t know how to jump into the code in debugger, well then, at least post us the error stack alongside the error message. Expand the error message, select all text, copy paste.

Comment: hi hackape, thanks heaps mate, I've create a new post with more information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645986/cant-get-pass-the-typeerror-cannot-read-property-id-of-undefined-at-produ  could you please have a look if you still keen to help ?