# Can't get pass the -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Long story short, I have a table where I've build a searching functionality using the following code to search in the object arrays and update the state using hooks.

```
  const SearchView = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value)

    if (!e.target.value) {
      setSearchDataSuggestions([])
      setSearchField(null)

    } else {

      setSearchField(true)
      props.setSeachingView(true)
      for (const row of Object.values(rows)) {
        Object.keys(row).forEach(function (item, index) {

          if (typeof(row[item]) === 'string' && row[item].toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim())) {
            setSearchDataSuggestions([...search_data_suggestions, (rows[index])   ])

          }

        });
        }

    }

  }
```

The code works as fine in the `npm start` but wont work at production build ...  Whenever I try to type something into the text field (where the SearchView() is called onChange) it crashes on a blank page along the following console error:

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKgAk.png)

I've no idea where this error is telling me ... Since there's no .id being passed whatsoever in my code. By any chance, I'm posting the entire code here anyways.

Can someone please help me identify where is the bug trigger and why it works fine in a dev server and not in prod !??!

Full code goes below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import moment from 'moment'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';


const LookUpTable = (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [rows, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [search_data_suggestions, setSearchDataSuggestions] = useState([]);

  const [accessToken] = useState(props.accessToken)
  const [isSearching] = useState(props.isSearching);
  const [search_field, setSearchField] = useState(null);


  const success_validation = row_success => {
    if (row_success) {
      return "True";
    } else {
        return "False";
    }
  };


  const columns = [
    {
      name: 'Timestamp',
      selector: 'timestamp',
      sortable: true,
      format: row => moment(row.timestamp).format('lll'),
    },
    {
      name: 'Project ID',
      selector: 'project_id',
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Client Name',
      selector: 'client_name',
      sortable: true,
      right: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Client Email',
      selector: 'client_email',
      sortable: true,
      right: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'Client Mobile',
      selector: 'client_mobile',
      sortable: true,

    },
    {
      name: 'Sent By',
      selector: 'sent_by',
      sortable: true,

    },
    {
      name: 'Success',
      selector: 'success_validation',
      sortable: true,
      right: true,
      format: row => success_validation(row.success),
    },
    ];

    const ExpanableComponent = ({ data }) => {
      return(
        <div>
          <p></p>
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Report Filename: </strong>{data.file_name} </li>
          <li><strong>Project Description: </strong>{data.project_desc} </li>
          <li><strong>Project Owner's Name: </strong>{data.project_owner_name} </li>
          <li><strong>Project Owner's Email: </strong>{data.project_owner_email} </li>
        </ul>  
        </div>
      )
    }


  const SearchView = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.value)
    // setSearchValue(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    // const values = (Object.values(rows));

    if (!e.target.value) {
      setSearchDataSuggestions([])
      setSearchField(null)


    } else {

      setSearchField(true)
      props.setSeachingView(true)
      for (const row of Object.values(rows)) {
        Object.keys(row).forEach(function (item, index) {
          // console.log('[' + index + '] ' + 'keys: ' + item + ' values : ' + row[item]);


          if (typeof(row[item]) === 'string' && row[item].toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase().trim())) {
            setSearchDataSuggestions([...search_data_suggestions, (rows[index])])
            // console.log('Got search as: ' + e.target.value + ' and updated with the row: ' + (rows[index]) )

          }

        });
        }

    }

  }

  const CustonSearchViewRender = () => {
    if (search_field) {
      return (
        <DataTable
        columns={columns}
        data={search_data_suggestions}
        highlightOnHover={true}
        pagination={true}
        fixedHeader={true}
        expandableRows={true}
        expandableRowsComponent={<ExpanableComponent />}
        striped={true}
      />
      )    

    }
  }


  // Note: the empty deps array [] means
  // this useEffect will run once
  // similar to componentDidMount()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/lookup/", {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      }
    }
    )

      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [accessToken])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
      return (
        <div className='lookup-table container-fluid'> 
        <div className="search-bar container"> 
        <br></br>
        <h4 className="search-bar-title">Past 90 days report table lookup ...</h4> 


      <TextField 
      label="Search me"
      onChange={e => SearchView(e)}
      variant="outlined"
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </InputAdornment>
        )
      }}
      />
      </div> 


      {isSearching && !search_field?       
      <DataTable
        columns={columns}
        data={rows}
        highlightOnHover={true}
        pagination={true}
        fixedHeader={true}
        expandableRows={true}
        expandableRowsComponent={<ExpanableComponent />}
        striped={true}
      /> : null}

    {search_field ? <CustonSearchViewRender/> : null}


        </div>
      );
  }
}


export default LookUpTable;
```

Thank you so much.